# Spawning a new shell process as a member of another ProcessGroup (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

**Problem.** I am trying spawn a new shell process, and forcing it to be a member of another existing process group, so that if my Haskell program dies, the spawned process is guaranteed to live. The following complains about permissions in my repl:

```hs
import System.Process
import Data.Int

createProcessWithGroup :: ProcessGroupID -> FilePath -> [String] -> Maybe [(String, String)] -> IO ProcessID
createProcessWithGroup pgid exe args env = forkProcess $ do
    joinProcessGroup pgid
    executeFile exe True args env

pidStr <- readProcess "pgrep" ["firefox"] []
let pid = CPid ((read pidStr) :: Int32)
gpid <- getProcessGroupIDOf pid -- :: ProcessID -> IO ProcessGroupID
putStrLn $ "gpid: " ++ (show gpid)

pid <- createProcessWithGroup gpid "gvim" [] Nothing
putStrLn $ "pid: " ++ (show pid)
```

outputs

```hs
joinProcessGroup: permission denied (Operation not permitted)
pid: 26341
```

I'm unable to run the original Haskell process as `root`. Is there a way around this?

Comment: This is a problem for whoever runs your program to solve, not your program itself. Typically, you would run this in something like `screen` or `tmux`.

Comment: I'm getting this in compiled programs as well?

Comment: You could try spawning eg `sh -c 'gvim & disown'`

Comment: Please post a minimal, reproducible example. What you posted has monadic code at top-level, which isn't legal Haskell and so can't be compiled and tested as-is.

Answer (score 1):

You can only change the process group of a process to an (existing) process group *in the same session*.  This is an operating system limitation.  See the manpage for the `setpgid` call.  Attempts to change the process group to a group in a different session will result in EPERM (even if you're root).

Most likely, your Haskell process is not in the same session as the `firefox` process, which would explain the error you're getting.  I find that if I launch Firefox from my window manager and run the following program in a terminal (so that Firefox belongs to `gnome-shell`'s session while the Haskell process belongs to my `bash` shell's session), I get:

```
gpid: 2692
pid: 12093
Setpgid.hs: joinProcessGroup: permission denied (Operation not permitted)
```

On the other hand, if I shut down Firefox completely, re-launch it in the background from the **same terminal** using `firefox &` just before running the program, the `joinProcessGroup` works fine (though I get a different error since I don't have `gvim` installed):

```
gpid: 12125
pid: 12359
Setpgid.hs: gvim: executeFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

Here's the test program I ran:

```
import System.Posix
import System.Process
import Data.Int

createProcessWithGroup :: ProcessGroupID -> FilePath -> [String] -> Maybe [(String, String)] -> IO ProcessID
createProcessWithGroup pgid exe args env = forkProcess $ do
    joinProcessGroup pgid
    executeFile exe True args env

main :: IO ()
main = do
  pidStr <- readProcess "pgrep" ["firefox"] []
  let pid = CPid ((read pidStr) :: Int32)
  gpid <- getProcessGroupIDOf pid -- :: ProcessID -> IO ProcessGroupID
  putStrLn $ "gpid: " ++ (show gpid)

  pid <- createProcessWithGroup gpid "gvim" [] Nothing
  putStrLn $ "pid: " ++ (show pid)
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is detaching the current process from the current process group, use `setsid(2)` and perhaps redirect standard stream file descriptors to `/dev/null`:

```hs
import System.Posix.Process
import System.Posix.IO

stdFds = [stdInput, stdOutput, stdError]

createProcessAsSessionLeader :: FilePath -> [String] -> Maybe [(String, String)] -> IO ProcessID
createProcessAsSessionLeader exe args env = forkProcess $ do
    -- use getProcessId >>= createProcessGroupFor to do setpgid(getpid(), 0) instead
    createSession
    -- a bracket or finally here is unnecessary here
    -- since the child process is short-lived.
    fd <- openFd "/dev/null" ReadWrite Nothing defaultFileFlags
    mapM_ (dupTo fd) stdFds
    closeFd fd
    executeFile exe True args env
```

but you could as well just do:

```hs
import System.Process
import System.IO

createProcessAsSessionLeader :: FilePath -> [String] -> Maybe [(String, String)] -> IO ProcessHandle
createProcessAsSessionLeader exe args env' =
    fmap (\(_, _, _, p) -> p) $
    withBinaryFile "/dev/null" ReadWriteMode $ \h ->
        let s = UseHandle h
        in createProcess $ proc exe args {
            env = env', std_in = s, std_out = s, std_err = s,
            -- use create_group = True to do setpgid(getpid(), 0) instead
            new_session = True
        }
```

If you *do* want to join an existing process group, make sure the attacher and the attachee have the same session id (not quite the same as the login session), but it's usually not the case. Otherwise, `setsid(2)` is also used by daemons, GUI program launches and screen multiplexers for this specific purpose.

If you're not trying to completely abandon the process then masking stdin only shall suffice, and that way stdout and stderr are not discarded. In any case, the child process is unresponsive to signals sent by the terminal since making a process a session leader disassociates it from the current controlling terminal (unless attached again).